# Can't run NPM from within init.d service

Tags: npm, init.d

I have a Node.js application I am trying to get to run / stop as an init.d service (I am not using systemd since I am using WSL2).

I am also using NVM, so node/npm exist within my user folder `/home/jlcarveth/.nvm/verions/node/v18.2.0/bin/...`

My init script is quite simple for now, I try to cd to the directory where my source code and package.json exist, and run `npm install` and `npm run`.

However, I always get the error `exec: npm: not found`, even if I explicitly link to the npm binary.

My init.d script:

```
export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/home/jlcarveth/.nvm/versions/node/v18.2.0/lib/node_modules
export NPM_PATH=$NPM_PATH:/home/jlcarveth/.nvm/versions/node/v18.2.0/bin/npm
export INSTALL_DIR=/opt/express-proxy

PROXY_LOG=/var/log/express-proxy/proxy.log
ERROR_LOG=/var/log/express-proxy/error.log

case "$1" in
    start)
    cd $INSTALL_DIR
    exec $NPM_PATH install
    exec $NPM_PATH run dev 1>>$PROXY_LOG 2>>$ERROR_LOG
    ;;

    stop)
    echo "Received shutdown signal from init.d. Exiting." >> $PROXY_LOG
    kill $(ps aux | grep 'eproxy' | awk '{print $2}')
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, I created a symlink of node and npm to `/usr/local/bin`:

```
sudo ln -s $(which node) /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s $(which npm) /usr/local/bin
```

I also added a PATH declaration to the beginning of the script:

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```